# From Maxwell equations, how do you derive that photons have spin 1

Tags: photons, quantum-spin, maxwell-equations

I understand that photons derive from the quantization of electromagnetic field, classically described by Maxwell equations. Can you, just by looking Maxwell equations, deduce that photons must have spin 1 ?

Comment: It's a general fact that the quanta associated to vector fields have spin-1, and that electrodynamics is described by the four-potential vector field at the level of the Lagrangian. For the precise method of quantization of vector fields, see any good QFT book.

Comment: This is a question related to @ACuriousMind's answer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47547/why-do-many-people-say-vector-fields-describe-spin-1-particle-but-omit-the-spin

Comment: Just to clarify ACuriousMind's comment: we don't quantise the electric or magnetic fields because they aren't individually Lorentz covariant. Instead we combine them to construct a four-vector field called the [electromagnetic four-potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential), usually denoted by $\mathbf A$. This vector field is what gets quantised. Since it's a vector field the quanta have spin 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Why do many people say vector fields describe spin-1 particle but omit the spin-0 part?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47547/why-do-many-people-say-vector-fields-describe-spin-1-particle-but-omit-the-spin0)